# Adding curves to path

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, coordinates, bezier

I'm trying to develop a javascript function to smooth the path between an array of coordinates by adding curves between those coordinates.

An example of user input would be the shape of a butterfly (an array of x/y coordinates of image):

[image]

The input would have sharpy edges like in this image and I'm trying to find a way to smooth those:

[image]

The result should be something similar to this (rounded edges):

[image]

I'm using react native and I've considered using Bezier curves but all the examples I've found rely on built in methods from browser/web canvas.

Has anyone advices for this approach (algorithms or code implementations), any suggest would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: SVG provides Bezier curves. The path in canvas and SVG is the same.

Comment: also maybe read up on active contours, or "snakes": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model (link so you can learn what all the relevant terms are, here. After that: web searching for implementations and programming tips is where it's at)